# Mysql size of tables is not immediately updated after delete

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which holds Logentries of several applications.
Now I have written a bash-Script which should delete the oldest day when a size limit is exceeded.
I have a loop which deletes day per day until the acctual size is smaller then the limit.
But after the delete-statements the size of the table is not properly updated.

I used this Sql Statement

```
'SELECT round(((data_length + index_length)), 0) "Size in Bytes" FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = "Log" AND table_name = "Log";'
```

to determine the acctual table size.
How can I force MySql to recaclulate this size immediately after a delete command?

Comment: you may try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html to update the stats, but it will also block your table until complete

Comment: You should understand how table statistics are held and refreshed. I'd start looking [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282041/when-does-mysql-update-the-indexes) and reading [this post](http://www.percona.com/blog/2011/10/06/when-does-innodb-update-table-statistics-and-when-it-can-bite/)

Comment: Don't you think this whole approach you described is completely wrong? You opt for checking the database size on disk. That's something for MySQL to worry about. It's not meant to be used as a file were you check some size and then perform logic. If you want to use MySQL for log storage (not the best idea) then store the info about size into another table upon inserting a log message. Databases are meant to be queried to obtain info, not to check their  metadata that's documented to be an approximation in many cases.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Run

```
 OPTIMIZE TABLE Log
```

After deleting. This will update the index statistics (and free all unused disk-space btw).

Comment: In MySQL 8 this is not enough. You need `ANALYZE TABLE` after it.

Comment: Same for MariaDB 10.4. `ANALYZE TABLE` to refresh the statistics.

Comment: In MySQL 5.7 running AWS aurora compatible, that is enough.

Comment: To be clear, if anyone is feeling confused -- don't actually optimize information_schema.log! That is a view and you cannot optimize it. Optimize the table you just did the delete/truncate on.

Answer (score 29):

```
ANALYZE TABLE tableName;
```

This is also possible for refreshing the table statistics.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: Worked for MySql 8 . This should be accepted answer.

Comment: Any tips for situations where I lose INSERT permissions when over a certain db size - but I need to recompute the table sizes in order to get back down UNDER that limit?

Comment: @T.Todua it doesn't matter. If you run `OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name` you get the response "Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead." So it's the same result either way. Tested on Mysql 8.0.22

Comment: @SmokinJoe are you sure you're not running out of disk space? Try posting a new question.

Comment: @ButtleButkus I still had to run ANALYZE after OPTIMIZE to update the size although I got the message you mentioned (using mysqld 8.0.25).